# How to start netcat listening server in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, netcat

I'm working on larger Ansible playbook. One of the tasks I'd like to use is to do "TCP ping" using `netcat`. On one of the hosts, I'd like to start a `netcat` 'server', and then start the 'client' to send any string to the server.

I'm testing this without Ansible -- everything works OK, but in Ansible `netcat` returns `1`. I know for a fact that it means that network connection was not established. Here's my `netcat` server task:

```yaml
- shell: |
    nc -d -q0 -l 1234
  poll: 0
  async: 60
```

However, this just doesn't work. I've tried adding ampersand at the end of command but without success. Another thing I did was to set poll to > 0  and then check on 'server' host whether the port has been opened (via `netstat -tulpn`). It was not.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing the mentioned command on CLI will result into an output of

```bash
nc -d -q0 -l 1234 &
[1] 123456
~/test$ Ncat: Invalid -d delay "-q0" (must be greater than 0). QUITTING.
^C
[1]+  Exit 2                  nc -d -q0 -l 1234
```

whereby a minimal example playbook of

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Start LISTENer on Remote Node
    shell:
      cmd: "nc --listen 1234"
    poll: 0
    async: 60 # seconds

  - name: Test from Control Node
    delegate_to: controlnode.example.com
    wait_for:
      host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      port: 1234
      state: drained
      delay: 0
      timeout: 3 # seconds
      active_connection_states: SYN_RECV

  - name: Test via nc
    delegate_to: controlnode.example.com
    shell:
      cmd: "nc -vz {{ inventory_hostname }} 1234"
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: result
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Start LISTENer on Remote Node] ************************
changed: [test1.example.com]
changed: [test2.example.com]
changed: [test3.example.com]

TASK [Test from Control Node] *******************************
ok: [test1.example.com -> controlnode.example.com]
ok: [test2.example.com -> controlnode.example.com]
ok: [test3.example.com -> controlnode.example.com]

TASK [Test via nc] ******************************************
changed: [test1.example.com -> controlnode.example.com]
changed: [test2.example.com -> controlnode.example.com]
changed: [test3.example.com -> controlnode.example.com]

TASK [Show result] ******************************************
ok: [test1.example.com] =>
  result:
    changed: true
    cmd: nc -vz test1.example.com 1234
    delta: '0:00:00.034145'
    end: '2023-01-28 13:30:00.291207'
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    rc: 0
    start: '2023-01-28 13:30:00.257062'
    stderr: |-
      Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
      Ncat: Connected to 192.168.2.1:1234.
      Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.02 seconds.
    stderr_lines:
    - 'Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )'
    - 'Ncat: Connected to 192.168.2.1:1234.'
    - 'Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.02 seconds.'
    stdout: ''
    stdout_lines: []
...
```

Regarding

> *One of the tasks I'd like to use is to do "TCP ping" ...*

it is recommended to use [`wait_for` module – Waits for a condition before continuing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html) instead of

> *... to do "TCP ping" using netcat.*

as one can see from the provided sample output already and because of the difference in the result sets and behavior.

**Further Documentation**

- [Asynchronous actions and polling - Run tasks concurrently: poll = 0](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html#run-tasks-concurrently-poll-0)